# Encoding issues with Spring and Freemarker

Tags: java, spring, encoding, jetty, freemarker

I'm working on a project using Freemarker and Spring running on Jetty.  It will involve displaying characters from many different countries so I'm trying to set the encoding to UTF-8.  However, no matter what I do, it remains ISO-8859-1.  I tried to create a filter in my web.xml and I've tried putting this

```
  response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

just before rendering the view.  But when I load the page and click "View Page Info", the encoding is always ISO-8859-1.  I've also tried hitting my app server directly to see if it was being affected by Apache but got the same result.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the spring character encoding filter in your web.xml ?
In my case I have the following:

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncoding</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```